# How to add tmux confirm prompt when I kill a window?

Tags: tmux

I see in `tmux`'s list-keys:

```
bind-key & confirm-before -p "kill-window #W? (y/n)" kill-window
```

I use `tmuxinator`, and will often go overboard on the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, where I accidentally close a window.  Is there a way to add this prompt to any window/pane I close, but only for those created by `tmuxinator`?  I don't want this for temporary or new windows, but just those that were created on my new session.

Comment: I also recommend adding a confirmation to detach, which can be quit startling if you don't intend to that and don't detach frequently! It's `-T prefix d`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the man page with a different binding.

```
unbind C-d                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
bind -n C-d confirm-before -p "kill-pane #P? (y/n)" kill-pane
```

`-n` tells tmux that you don't need to enter the prefix before.

In case the command you want to trigger has more than one word like `respawn-pane -k`, then you need to enclose the command in double quotes.

```
 bind X  confirm -p "Do you want to kill the pane?" "respawn-pane -k";
```

Comment: Now it overrides VIM's page down shortcut which is also C-d. So can not use it